# total variation inequality involving cross variation

Tags: stochastic-calculus, quadratic-variation, total-variation

It's from *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus* by I. Karatzas chapter 1, problem 5.7 property (iv) trying to show an inequality wrt total variation and cross variation of martingales.

$$\check{\xi}_t - \check{\xi}_s\le \frac{1}{2}[\langle X\rangle_t+\langle Y\rangle_t-(\langle X\rangle_s+\langle Y\rangle_s)]$$
where $X$ and $Y$ are two martingales and $\check{\xi}_t$ is the total variation of the cross variation $\langle X,Y\rangle_t$ on $[0,t]$.

For now, I know how to show that $\check{\xi}_t\le \frac{1}{2}[\langle X\rangle_t+\langle Y\rangle_t]$ using $\langle X-Y\rangle\ge0$ but as for the $s$-term, I don't know how to deal with it.

It is said to be the final step to verify that cross variation is a bilinear function but I really don't understand why aren't the first three properties sufficient to show the result. I'll appreciate help of any kind. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties (i) and (ii) show that $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is a bilinear form. Properties (iii) and (iv) seem to be extra properties.

---

Let $0\le s< t$.

Observation 1. Suppose $h$ is given by the difference between two nondecreasing functions $f$ and $g$: $h=f-g$. Then $\check h(t)-\check h(s)\le f(t)-f(s)$.

Proof. $|f(t_2)-g(t_2)-f(t_1)+g(t_1)|\le f(t_2)-f(t_1)$, so $\sum_i|h(t_{i+1})-h(t_i)|\le f(t)-f(s)$ for any partition.

Observation 2. For any function $f$ of bounded variation, $f(t)-f(s)\le \check f(t)-\check f(s)$.

Now Property (iv):
\begin{align}
\check\xi_t-\check\xi_s
&\le \frac{1}{4}\left(\langle X+Y\rangle_t-\langle X+Y\rangle_s\right),\quad\text{Observation 1},\\
&=\frac{1}{4}(
\langle X\rangle_t-\langle X\rangle_s+\langle Y\rangle_t-\langle Y\rangle_s
+2\langle X,Y\rangle_t-2\langle X,Y\rangle_s
),\quad\text{Properties (i) and (ii)},\\
&\le \frac{1}{4}(
\langle X\rangle_t-\langle X\rangle_s+\langle Y\rangle_t-\langle Y\rangle_s
+2(\check\xi_t-\check\xi_s)
),\quad\text{Observation 2},
\end{align}
which, rearranged, yields the desired inequality.

Comment: @JacobG. You're welcome. In the meantime, you could perhaps "accept" this answer ;) https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Observation 1 doesn't seem correct; for example when $f$ is constant.

Comment: @WittyViper If $f$ is constant, then LHS is non-positive and RHS is $0$ in the inequality.